# How can I get JSHint configured on a Jenkins server?

Tags: jenkins, jshint

I'm relatively new to Jenkins and I'm attempting to add JSHint to my build process. Currently, I have the "Checkstyle Plug-in", "JSHint Report Plug-in", and "Violations plugin" installed on my Jenkins server. In 'Jenkins->Configure->Build->Execute shell' I have the following:

```
jshint --verbose --reporter=checkstyle > jshint.xml || exit 0
```

But I'm not exactly sure what's going on here. I found similar commands on other tutorials, but they were half-baked and didn't fully explain what this line of code does.

My goal is to run JSHint on my Jenkins server and send the output/results from JSHint to a file that I can then email to the admin. Any explanation about what the above line of code is suppose to do would be much appreciated. Any links or suggestions on how to add JSHint to a Jenkins build would also be helpful. Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1):

First part of command:

```
jshint --verbose --reporter=checkstyle
```

is jshint call with two parameters to turn on verbose mode and export report in checkstyle compatibile format. (Checkstyle is used because Jenkins was originaly designed for Java and Checkstyle is one of Java linting tools -> Jenkins Checkstyle plugin can pick up such formatted report)

Second part:

```
> jshint.xml
```

Is linux shell redirection from standard console into file called jshint.xml. This will save your report into file.

Third part:

```
|| exit 0
```

Seem to me unnecessary because it does logical OR with exit code values of commands on both sides. Command on right side is saving jshint report into file and command on right side returns 0 error code. So final error code seem to be output of command on right side anyway.